# Copying tables from a .sql to a .db file.. Learn SQL The Hard Way

Tags: sqlite

I'm pretty sure there is a simple answer to this but I can't find it anywhere and can't seem to figure it out for myself.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to copy a table from a `.sql` file (`ex1.sql`) that has a basic table in it. I can create this no problem but then I'm running the following to copy this table into a database (`ex1.db`):

```
sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql
```

I'm getting the following response

> C:\SQLite>sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql
>   onperson CREATE TABLE person (format 3)      NB: smileyface symbol after "onperson"
>   first_name text,
>   last_name text,
>   age integer
>   )

It looks like the table is being replicated in the database or am I getting this wrong?

Anyway, when I then go back into the ex1.db there is no table there.

Any idea as to why this isn't saving? Do I need to add further commands to this to get it to save in the db file?

Apologies if this is a stupid question. Rather new to this.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the contents of `ex1.sql`? Where does this file come from?

Comment: I created it by doing the following: 

$ sqlite3 ex1.sql

and then I created a table inside it which was:

create table person (id integer primary key, first_name text, last_name text, age integer);

for reference I'm following this guide: http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex1.html

Comment: I've figured this out.. I was creating the .sql file within SQLite3 rather than producing it in Notepad and importing it into the database that way. Apologies and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact problem, and I have never touched SQLite before.  Here are more instructions for people in the future.

In a text editor, create `ex1.sql`.  This is the file that will be used to create the `.db` when the command `sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql` is run.

**ex1.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    age INTEGER
);
```

Make sure to save this file in the same folder as the `sqlite3.exe` file you downloaded.  You can now run the aforementioned command and you are good to go!