# Learn SQL the hard way - exercise 1. sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql not working

Tags: sql, sqlite

Learn SQL The Hard Way - Exercise 1. http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex1.html

The hard way indeed.

I first had to google around to find that for the

```
> sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql
```

command to work, you have to manually create the .sql file first. But when there is a file and I type

```
D:\SQL> sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql
```

it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all. The file size stays 0 bytes.

```
D:\Sql>sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql

D:\Sql>dir

Directory of D:\Sql

06-01-2015  13:01    <DIR>          .
06-01-2015  13:01    <DIR>          ..
06-01-2015  13:00             4.096 ex1.db
06-01-2015  12:51                 0 ex1.sql
```

I'm currently at exercise 6 and everything else IS working. (I can `SELECT` in the table I created).

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the SQL statement(s) into the SQL file, and that tutorial is implying you should put:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    age INTEGER
);
```

in ex1.sql

Comment: Thank you! And: Oops. I put that in ex1.db ! What's the difference between .db and .sql ? I thought the db stood for 'databse' so figured that should be the thing to hold all the tables... Re-reading the explanation. So I manually create the .sql file, then do the `CREATE` in the command line, and then the sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql command generates the matching .db file for me?

Comment: The .db is the database data and schema, whilst the sql is the commend to execute, in this case to create the actual empty database

Comment: I'm still doing something wrong. Here is my current process: I manually create 2 empty files ex2.sql and ex2.db . With the command line I add the "CREATE" code to the .sql file (the size of that file changes, and `> .schema` returns the code fine so this is working). Then I try to run `sqlite3 ex2.db < ex2.sql` (this is supposed to execute the code in the SQL file on the DB file, right? So it should actually create the tables), but then my command window bleeps at me in error and returns some of the code with gibberish smiley faces mixed in. The filesize of the .db file does not change either.

Comment: Found the cause. I created the .sql file through the command line, while it should be created in a text editor. (with thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048938/copying-tables-from-a-sql-to-a-db-file-learn-sql-the-hard-way?rq=1 found through the sidebar). It seems to be working fine now. Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 1):

(with thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25213083/1692094 which I found through the sidebar)

Fixed. The problem was that I created the .sql file through the sqlite3 command line, while it should be created in a regular text editor. Everything seems to be working now.

**Correct steps:**

Open Notepad (or other text editor) and type

```
CREATE TABLE person (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
first_name TEXT,
last_name TEXT,
age INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE pet (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name TEXT,
breed TEXT,
age INTEGER,
dead INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE person_pet (
person_id INTEGER,
pet_id INTEGER
);
```

Save the file as ex2.sql

Open Command prompt and type `>sqlite3 ex2.db < ex2.sql` . The ex2.db file will be generated using the code from the ex2.sql file.